# QBXML get all inactive and active customers

Tags: qbxml

I am trying to get all customers from QuickBooks 2012 desktop using QBWebConnector. My request QBXML is as follows

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
  <?qbxml version="11.0"?> 
- <QBXML>
- <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
- <CustomerQueryRq requestID="1" iterator="Start">
  <ActiveStatus>All</ActiveStatus> 
  <MaxReturned>50</MaxReturned> 
  </CustomerQueryRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
  </QBXML>
```

This request is failing and error message in the log is as follows

```
20150101.15:06:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.CompanyFileLock.getLock() : Got Lock = LOCKED:MAQBOOL-PC:635557215943733778
20150101.15:06:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.update() : Company file has been locked for update.
20150101.15:06:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.update() : Synchronizing with QuickBooks Company Name = Birmingham Islamic Society
20150101.15:06:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : Asking application to send request no. 1
20150101.15:06:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : *** Calling sendRequestXML() with following parameters:
20150101.15:06:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : wcTicket="54f77c33-8193-4712-8bd8-0a6ceb402b9e"
20150101.15:06:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : HCPResponseXML=
20150101.15:06:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : XML dump follows: -

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRs>
<HostQueryRs requestID="0" sta......

20150101.15:06:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : cfn="C:\QB\xxxxxxx111214.QBW"
20150101.15:06:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : qbNationality="US"
20150101.15:06:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : qbXMLMajorVers="11"
20150101.15:06:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : qbXMLMinorVers="0"
20150101.15:06:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : Received from sendRequestXML() following parameter:
20150101.15:06:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : strRequestXML =
20150101.15:06:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : XML dump follows: -

<?xml version="1.0"?><?qbxml version="11.0"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError="s......

20150101.15:06:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : Request xml received.
20150101.15:06:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Processing request #1
20150101.15:06:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : REQUEST: received from application: size (bytes) = 234
20150101.15:06:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Sending request to QuickBooks.
20150101.15:06:41 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Sending error message back to application:
HRESULT = 0x80040400
Message: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.
20150101.15:06:41 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : XML dump follows: -

Request that failed:

<?xml version="1.0"?><?qbxml version="11.0"?><QBXML......
```

However, if I remove `<ActiveStatus>All</ActiveStatus>` from my request, it works but I only get the active members, which I believe is the default. I want to get inactive members also. I have tied all three values, ActiveOnly, InactiveOnly and All, I always get the same error. It works when I remove the element.

From Intuit OnScreen reference...

ActiveStatus may have one of the following values: ActiveOnly [DEFAULT], InactiveOnly, All

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Environment:
.Net 4.0 WCF service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveStatus must FOLLOW MaxRetuned

Sequence is important

Comment: Thanks, did not realize the order was important. The Onscreen Reference manual has it in correct order. Thanks.

Comment: (for the person who answered) Can you explain this answer with more details? and  (for the question person)
 @user618886 can you tell me what did you do that it worked? i am assigned to get the customer detail. I think this is it.. But What is ActiveStatus and what MaxReturn exactly means? to get (all active and unActive users)

Comment: Has been a while, I looked up my notes, basically I had to change the seq in the request. The original req had <ActiveStatus>  followed by <MaxReturned>. For it to work I had to switch the order, <MaxReturned> followed by <ActiveStatus>